# after upgrate to Bokeh 2.1.1 Figure is not displaying on Web Site

Tags: python, bokeh

> Blockquote
> from bokeh.io import output_file
> from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

```
x = [1, 2, 1]
y = [1, 1, 2]
```

output_file('first_glyphs.html', title='First Glyphs')

```
fig = figure(title='My Coordinates',
         plot_height=300, plot_width=300,
         x_range=(0, 3), y_range=(0, 3),
         toolbar_location=None)
fig.circle(x=x, y=y,
       color='green', size=10, alpha=0.5)
show(fig)
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the Python output or JavaScript console?

Comment: The code above works fine with Bokeh 2.1.1 you need to provide something closer to your actual code that is not working. Also, please edit your post to use code formatting for code blocks.